# How can i invoke constructor implicitly and explicitly?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I have class A and write a subclass B, C.A have only one constructor which is parameterized. C has to call this super constructor of B, B has to call this super constructor of A. Now i want to use on object as a parameter. So the parameter object has to hold a reference of C.

> Language : java

**Calss A:**

```
public class A {

private C c;


protected A(C c) {
    this.c = c;
}
}
```

**Class B:**

```
public class B extends A {

protected B(C c) {
    super(c);
}
}
```

**Class C:**

[image]

Now when i want to invoke the constructor like, Eclipse says:

```
Cannot refer to 'this' nor 'super' while explicitly invoking a constructor
```

how can i invoke the super class constructor with "this" instance.
kindly explain this error and give the solution to this.

Comment: Why are you tagging C++ or Java-ee? I suspect tag-spam just to increase attention to your question. Please don't do this, unless the attention you want to draw is negative.

Comment: Your program structure may be broken -- a super class should not require knowledge or use of its own sub-class.

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass `this` to `A`? Since `C` is a subtype of `A`, `A` already has it (also by using `this`).

Answer (score 0):

> how can i invoke the super class constructor with "this" instance.

You can't.

> give the solution to this.

Change `super(this)` to `super(null)`.

> How can i invoke constructor implicitly

By using reflection, like calling [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) on the class object. Or using a factory method. Or using the `new` keyword.